# Query Checklist and post multiple results to table in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Hello guys im trying to post several checklist values to a single table in my database but it only takes one single value into the table...

Im doing it like this:

The Form:

```
 <?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="tipoinsertos" value="<?= $user['tipoinsertom']; ?>"> <?= $user['tipoinsertom']; ?> 
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

And this is my post form:

```
$data = array('tipoinsertos' => $_POST['tipoinsertos']);

try {

    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $query = "INSERT INTO barrasinternas ( tipoinsertos ) VALUES (:tipoinsertos )"; 


    $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $sth->execute($data);
    echo "&iexcl;A&ntilde;adida Exitosamente!";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
$dbh = null;
?>
```

check this prints:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/caZ6y.jpg

So I checked all 3 values but only one was in my table.

Comment: `name="tipoinsertos"` needs to be treated as an array `name="tipoinsertos[]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, use an array for your input name `tipoinsertos[]`

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tipoinsertos[]" ...
```

Then you don't show how you're getting `$data` but you need to be iterating and executing that query somehow in a loop. Either by building it up into one big query of values, or by executing another statement with one value over and over. [Here's a possible solution](https://github.com/scratchers/stackoverflow-a-40445438-4233593):

```
<?php

$users = [
    ['tipoinsertom' => 'Jonatan'],
    ['tipoinsertom' => 'jeff'],
    ['tipoinsertom' => 'joe'],
];

?>

<form method="POST">

<?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tipoinsertos[]" value="<?= $user['tipoinsertom']; ?>"> <?= $user['tipoinsertom']; ?> 
<?php endforeach; ?>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<?php

// returns an intance of PDO
// https://github.com/jpuck/qdbp
$dbh = require __DIR__.'/tipoin_Dxa05i_A.pdo.php';


if( !empty( $_POST['tipoinsertos'] ) ){
    // prepare the query once
    $query = "INSERT INTO barrasinternas (tipoinsertos ) VALUES (:tipoinsertos )";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);

    // iterate through list
    foreach($_POST['tipoinsertos'] as $tipoinsertos){
        $sth->execute(['tipoinsertos' => $tipoinsertos]);
    }

    // success
    echo "&iexcl;A&ntilde;adida Exitosamente!";
    $dbh = null;
}
```

Comment: I've updated OP to show where i'm getting $data.. 
I get a syntax error in $sth->execute(['tipoinsertos' => $tipoinsertos]);
Somehow it worked but in my table it shows "Array".

Comment: right, because the way you're doing it now is your trying to implicitly cast a whole array of values to a string intended for only one value. see the difference in my answer, and notice how I iterate through the array when executing.

Comment: Thanks, after a night of sleep, i've figured it out!!